# where can I find the log produced by Slog.w

Tags: android, logging

I am reading the android source code ,in which there are many places using Slog.w,for example

Slog.w(TAG, "Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.");

the question is  where I can find  the output log

Comment: Hi, I see you're pretty new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps you to get better answer on sucesive questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

> adb logcat -b system

By doing this, you will see logs from de 'system' buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,you let me know the adb logcat command,but I still can not  find the outputs that should be printed on the cmd console